Как сделать бордер более похожим?


.elem {
  position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #71b219;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #71b219;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="elem"></div>
</body>
</html>





А что сейчас не так? Я вижу что разве что border-bottom можно чуть потоньше сделать

-1 С читаю вопрос бесполезным для общества слишком очевидно как по мне. Для того кто хотя бы немного изучал что такое css и border и человек не попытался изначально решить вопрос сам.

Вот так можно реализовать


.elem {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #71b219;
  border-left: 1px solid #71b219;
  border-right: 1px solid #71b219;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #71b219;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
<div class="elem"></div>



На примере border-bottom чуть тоньше, чем у Вас, и border-radius чуть меньше, чем у Вас
